# How to scrape data from within a comment block and create a dataframe?

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull HTML data from baseball-reference.com. I thought going to their website, viewing the page source, the html tags would be within the html code itself. However, after further investigation, the set of html tags that I care about are within comment blocks.

Example: https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/AL/2021-standard-batting.shtml
Find the tag by "Viewing Source Code":

```
<div class="table_container" id="div_players_standard_batting">
```

The code I am looking for is below this line. And if you look above this line, you will see the comment block start <!-- and doesn't end until almost the end of the HTML file.

I can pull the HTML comments with the following code, but it comes with a few issues.

1. It is in a list and I care only about the one that has the data
2. It comes with new line tags
3. I am struggling on how to take the players standard batting string code and reparse it as html code to use BeautifulSoup to grab the data I want.

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Comment
import pandas as pd
import os.path
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/majors/2021-standard-batting.shtml")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser") # try lxml

Data=[x.extract() for x in soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))]
Data
```

Current Environment Settings:

```
dependencies:
  - python=3.9.7
  - beautifulsoup4=4.11.1
  - jupyterlab=3.3.2
  - pandas=1.4.2
  - pyodbc=4.0.32
```

The end goal:
Be able to have a pandas dataframe that has each player's data from this web page.

EDIT:

ANSWER:

Changes made to get to my goal:
Installed the lxml package via Anaconda Prompt into my environment.
Used the following line of code to pull my html data into a dataframe (Provided by: HedgeHog - Thank You!)

```
pd.read_html([x.extract() for x in soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)) if 'id="div_players_standard_batting"' in x][0])[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, you just have to put the individual parts together.

In the `ResultSet` there should be only one element with id `div_players_standard_batting`, so filter for it and take this element to transform it with `pandas.read_html()` to a DataFrame:

```
pd.read_html([x.extract() for x in soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)) if 'id="div_players_standard_batting"' in x][0])[0]
```

or as alternative create a new `bs4 object` and iterate over its rows:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup([x.extract() for x in soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)) if 'id="div_players_standard_batting"' in x][0])
for row in soup.select('table tr'):
    ...
```

Output:

|  | Rk | Name | Age | Tm | Lg | G | PA | AB | R | H | 2B | 3B | HR | RBI | SB | CS | BB | SO | BA | OBP | SLG | OPS | OPS+ | TB | GDP | HBP | SH | SF | IBB | Pos Summary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Fernando Abad* | 35 | BAL | AL | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | Cory Abbott | 25 | CHC | NL | 8 | 3 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0.333 | 0.333 | 0.333 | 0.667 | 81 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | /1H |
| 2 | 3 | Albert Abreu | 25 | NYY | AL | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | Bryan Abreu | 24 | HOU | AL | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 5 | José Abreu | 34 | CHW | AL | 152 | 659 | 566 | 86 | 148 | 30 | 2 | 30 | 117 | 1 | 0 | 61 | 143 | 0.261 | 0.351 | 0.481 | 0.831 | 125 | 272 | 28 | 22 | 0 | 10 | 3 | *3D/5 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1787 | 1720 | Bruce Zimmermann* | 26 | BAL | AL | 2 | 4 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | -100 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1788 | 1721 | Jordan Zimmermann | 35 | MIL | NL | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | -100 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | /1 |
| 1789 | 1722 | Tyler Zuber | 26 | KCR | AL | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | -100 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1790 | 1723 | Mike Zunino | 30 | TBR | AL | 109 | 375 | 333 | 64 | 72 | 11 | 2 | 33 | 62 | 0 | 0 | 34 | 132 | 0.216 | 0.301 | 0.559 | 0.86 | 137 | 186 | 7 | 7 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2/H |
| 1791 | nan | LgAvg per 600 PA | nan | nan | nan | 205 | 600 | 535 | 73 | 130 | 26 | 2 | 20 | 69 | 7 | 2 | 52 | 139 | 0.243 | 0.316 | 0.41 | 0.726 | nan | 219 | 11 | 7 | 2 | 4 | 2 | nan |

---

###### EDIT

To get rid of unwanted rows, exclude in column Rk the **NaN** and **Rk** values:

```
df1 = df1[(~df1.Rk.isna()) & (df1.Rk != 'Rk')]
```

Answer (score 0):

First pull raw html and then remove comments with `str.replace` using regex. Then parse it with `beautifulsoup4`. I think this will do the trick

Comment: The issue with removing comment tags with regex is that there is some comments within the code that are not HTML tags and are actual comments. Once you would parse it with beautifulsoup4, it would error out because of syntax issues.