# How to scrape specific element with a certain id in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the `table` from baseball reference: [https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/b/bondsba01.shtml](https://stackoverflow.com), and [the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtKM0.png) I want is the one with `id="batting_value"`, but when I trying to `print` out what I have scraped, the program returned an empty `list` instead. Any information or assistance is appreciated, thanks!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

root_page = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/b/bondsba01.shtml"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(root_page), features = 'lxml')

table = soup.find('table', id = 'batting_value')
print(table)
```

I've tried to `print` the `<div>` with `id="div_batting_value"` which contains the `table` in it, but still doesn't work. However, I can successfully print out other `<div>` elements with different `id`.

Comment: That div (`id="div_batting_value"`) is commented out in the rendered html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main issue here is that the `table` is hidden in the comments, so you have to bring it up first, before `BeautifulSoup` could find it - simplest solution in my opinion is to replace the specific characters in this case:

```
.replace('<!--','').replace('-->','')
```

Alternative is to be more specific and use [`bs4.Comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72416936/14460824)

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get('https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/b/bondsba01.shtml').text.replace('<!--','').replace('-->','')
)
soup.select_one('#batting_value')
```

Or in use with `pandas.read_html()`:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(requests.get('https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/b/bondsba01.shtml').text.replace('<!--','').replace('-->',''), attrs={'id':'batting_value'})[0]
df[(~df.Lg.isna()) & (df.Lg != 'Lg')]
```

Results in:

|  | Year | Age | Tm | Lg | G | PA | Rbat | Rbaser | Rdp | Rfield | Rpos | RAA | WAA | Rrep | RAR | WAR | waaWL% | 162WL% | oWAR | dWAR | oRAR | Salary | Pos | Awards |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1986 | 21 | PIT | NL | 113 | 484 | 3 | 5 | 0 | 8 | 1 | 17 | 1.9 | 16 | 34 | 3.5 | 0.517 | 0.512 | 2.6 | 1 | 25 | $60,000 | *8/H | RoY-6 |
| 1 | 1987 | 22 | PIT | NL | 150 | 611 | 11 | 3 | 1 | 24 | -3 | 36 | 3.7 | 21 | 57 | 5.8 | 0.525 | 0.523 | 3.2 | 2.1 | 33 | $100,000 | *78H/9 | nan |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 20 | 2006 | 41 | SFG | NL | 130 | 493 | 30 | 1 | 0 | 1 | -4 | 27 | 2.5 | 15 | 42 | 4 | 0.52 | 0.516 | 3.9 | -0.4 | 41 | $19,331,470 | *7H/D | nan |
| 21 | 2007 | 42 | SFG | NL | 126 | 477 | 37 | -1 | -1 | -10 | -4 | 21 | 2 | 15 | 36 | 3.4 | 0.516 | 0.513 | 4.4 | -1.5 | 46 | $15,533,970 | *7H/D | AS |

Comment: This is amazing !! Thank you for solving my problem and give extra information on how to retrieve data using pandas

Answer (score 0):

There is only one table on the page:

```
print(len(soup.find_all('table')))
```

output: 1

You can use simple find to get the table:

```
table = soup.find_all('table'))
```

And work with it. For example, there are rows:

```
table.find('tbody').find_all('th')
```

Does this solve your task?

Comment: The table they seek is not part of the live html. It exists as a comment