# Why is BeautifulSoup not pulling all tables from Baseball Reference?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull all the tables from this link: https://www.baseball-reference.com/awards/awards_2017.shtml

But I am only getting the first two tables, `AL MVP Voting` & `NL MVP Voting` but I'm not getting any of the tables after it, `AL/NL Cy Young Voting, AL/NL Rookie of the Year Voting`, etc.

Heres the code I am using:

```
url = f'https://www.baseball-reference.com/awards/awards_2017.shtml'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html')
soup

table = soup.find_all('table')
table[2]
```

I tried the code and expected all tables to come up but I am only getting the first 2, and am getting `None` for the third one and beyond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tables are embedded and hidden in comments, so simplest way to bring them up would be to uncomment them for example with `.replace('<!--','').replace('-->','')`

An alternative to be more specific is the use of [bs4.Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72416936/14460824)

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get('https://www.baseball-reference.com/awards/awards_2017.shtml').text.replace('<!--','').replace('-->','')
)
table = soup.find_all('table')
table[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing to look at if a tool is having trouble scraping a website is to check that the HTML you're looking at is valid.

I passed that page to the validator at https://validator.w3.org/ and it found a few structural errors that might confound a parser. According to the report it generated, there's a  tag that's closed incorrectly, and an unclosed .

One other note: I don't see any reason you need to have `url` be an f-string.